# Plain Tex | Setting hanging indent

Tags: indentation, tex-core

Returning to TeX after too many years away and so the simplest of tasks is throwing me…

I have set up a hanging indent so:

```
\hangindent=12pt \hangafter=1
```

and an example of my input file is

```
\mark{bay leaves at funerals} Bay leaves at funerals,
{\os{}1}s~ii~{\os{}196}.

\mark{bee superstitions} Bee superstitions,
{\os{}1}s~ii~{\os{}165};
{\os{}1}s~ii~{\os{}356};
{\os{}1}s~iv~{\os{}436};
{\os{}1}s~v~{\os{}148};
{\os{}1}s~v~{\os{}437};
{\os{}1}s~x~{\os{}321};
{\os{}1}s~xii~{\os{}38};
{\os{}1}s~xii~{\os{}200};
{\os{}1}s~xii~{\os{}488}.
```

and what I see is:

[image]

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Please make your examples in a form that people can use to test answers, ie a single test file, ending with `\bye` and defining any macros used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\hangindent` is restored at the end of the paragraph, so you need to re-assert it for the second paragraph.